# How to run a dll from Thunderbird and get a return value

Tags: thunderbird

I have a dll and I'd like to run it from Thunderbird and get a return value.
Is there an extension that already does it?

Thanks
Alb

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using js-ctypes. Here is an example from MDN:

```
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/ctypes.jsm");

var lib = ctypes.open("C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\user32.dll");

/* Declare the signature of the function we are going to call */
var msgBox = lib.declare("MessageBoxW",
                         ctypes.winapi_abi,
                         ctypes.int32_t,
                         ctypes.int32_t,
                         ctypes.jschar.ptr,
                         ctypes.jschar.ptr,
                         ctypes.int32_t);
var MB_OK = 0;

var ret = msgBox(0, "Hello world", "title", MB_OK);

lib.close();
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes for more details and examples.

Comment: Hi,I will try as your suggestment. Thanks a lot for your help